# Webpage won't parse PHP code

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add some of my own PHP to a nearly-unreadable template file on a forum system. I know it all works perfectly as far as the server config, etc. goes, but PHP simply doesn't parse on this page. JS works fine. Any ideas? It's a simple .html page.

Comment: another guess into the blue: forum doesn't pipe those template files  through php.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your .htaccess (or creating a new one in the appropriate directory):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

Comment: Good idea but doesn't work. I think this is on the right track though.

Comment: Maybe .htaccess are disabled from your httpd.conf. Look for the line `AllowOverride None` and change it to `AllowOverride All`, and see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: .htaccess is enabled, I've made changes to it before that have shown up.

Comment: @Andrei Korchagin - You have to restart the server.

Comment: @Andrei Korchagin - then try adding the RemoveHandler directive as per @Pradeep's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that the template file is being read into a variable rather than being included or required? Eg. it's loaded using file_get_contents or something similar?

If this is the case you may need to eval() the template code after it has been loaded as file_get_contents does not parse php code, it just loads the text as it is into a variable. It's a very ugly solution but it may work for you. Please be careful if you do this as it does open up a whole can of security issue worms.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of template systems use their own coding syntax. If this is the case it will not be possible to include PHP code in your template without opening up a lot of security holes.

Try to learn the specific templating language used, or find out where you should put the code without changing the template file (there may be a controller or plugin system built for such stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Your page has to be a .php page.